# What research has been done in the domain of “general game playing”?

Tags: reference-request, game-ai, research, state-of-the-art

I have come across this domain via this Wikipedia article: [General game playing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_game_playing)

So, where are we when it comes to general game playing AI? (The wiki article doesn't mention the recent advances and the achievements of this domain of research, except the annual games results.)

PS: I understand that this is a General project of the Stanford Logic Group of Stanford University, California. But since then, it has become an area of research in the domain of AI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't already come across DeepMind's advances in developing general game playing AI, you can take a look at it's [DQN research](https://deepmind.com/research/dqn/). The paper describes how their deep reinforcement learning system is able to beat human levels in nearly Atari 2600 games with raw pixels and scores as input.

Also here's an interesting website - [General Video Game AI Competition 2017](http://www.gvgai.net/) that also hosts links to the latest advances and research papers in this field.